# Distance between two distributions with uncertainty / measurement error

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, distance, uncertainty

I have two empirical distributions $X$ and $Y$, both with the same number of samples (a few thousand). $X$ are true values, they are accurate (i.e. no uncertainty). Values of $Y$, on the other hand, are measured with some error. The error distribution $Z$ is also known, on the same number of samples.

I want to know if $Y$ is larger than $X$, i.e. statistically significantly larger. Neither of them is close to normal (Gaussian).

If $X$ and $Y$ were both known exactly, it would be easy. I know I can calculate the distance between them easily (e.g. earth mover's distance, or KL-divergence), but this does not take into consideration that values of $Y$ are not exact, and also there is no telling if distance is significant at all.

How can I approach this?

EDIT: $Z$ error distribution:
[image]

Comment: What assumptions can you place on $Z?? I don't see how this is possible otherwise -- e.g., your noise could be such that $Y$ appears to be any given distribution.

Comment: @chang_trenton I added plot of $Z$ to description. I think I can quite reasonably assume it's an exponential distribution.